# Proguard say input jar file is specified twice

Tags: android, proguard

I create app with Google Translator. I try create signed apk with Proguard.

proguard.cfg contain:

```
-libraryjars libs/gtranslateapi-1.0.jar
-keep class com.gtranslate.** { *; }
```

proguard-project.txt contain:

```
-dontwarn com.gtranslate.**
```

Also I try without proguard-project.txt:

```
# -dontwarn com.gtranslate.**
```

But I get error:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
Error: The same input jar [C:\workspace\myproject\libs\gtranslateapi-1.0.jar] is specified twice.
```

What is incorrect?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Remove `-libraryjars libs/gtranslateapi-1.0.jar` from your `proguard.cfg` file.